# Firebase Database JSON loading time

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Database to store JSON with a size of 5MB. I would like to download this JSON and store it locally, but the speed of response is not good:

```
10-03 22:44:10.514 D: I'm started
10-03 22:47:39.909 D: I'm finished
```

And the code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "I'm started");
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I'm finished");
            }
        }
```

Is it a good time response? How to reduce this? I'm not sure that my WiFi is fast, but maybe the size of the JSON is very huge?

**Edit**

After I have setted `database.setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` the log starts with:

```
10-05 23:01:51.853 W: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
10-05 23:01:51.874 I: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4
10-05 23:01:51.874 I: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 4
10-05 23:01:51.881 W: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000005/n/x86
10-05 23:01:51.891 D: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
10-05 23:01:51.891 D: Scheduling retry in 0ms
10-05 23:01:51.903 D: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
10-05 23:01:51.916 D: pc_0 - Listening on / (params: {})
10-05 23:01:51.916 D: pc_0 - Adding listen query: / (params: {})
10-05 23:01:51.916 D: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
10-05 23:01:51.923 D: conn_0 - Opening a connection
10-05 23:01:52.683 D: ws_0 - websocket opened
10-05 23:01:52.683 D: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive
10-05 23:01:52.707 D: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"c","d":{"t":"r","d":"s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com"}}
10-05 23:01:52.708 D: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44975
10-05 23:01:52.709 D: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
10-05 23:01:52.713 D: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={d=s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com, t=r}, t=c}
10-05 23:01:52.713 D: conn_0 - Got control message: {d=s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com, t=r}
10-05 23:01:52.713 D: conn_0 - Got a reset; killing connection to daugavpils-1efea.firebaseio.com; Updating internalHost to s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com
10-05 23:01:52.714 D: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
10-05 23:01:52.714 D: ws_0 - websocket is being closed
10-05 23:01:52.714 D: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to SERVER_RESET
10-05 23:01:52.714 D: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
10-05 23:01:52.715 D: Scheduling retry in 0ms
10-05 23:01:52.716 D: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
10-05 23:01:52.717 D: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
10-05 23:01:52.722 D: conn_1 - Opening a connection
10-05 23:01:52.723 D: ws_0 - WebSocket reached EOF.
10-05 23:01:52.725 D: ws_0 - closed
10-05 23:01:53.462 D: ws_1 - websocket opened
10-05 23:01:53.462 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive
10-05 23:01:53.463 D: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1475697713467,"v":"5","h":"s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com","s":"aiVwAqOfKkxgXWZdYejceVrlivZ8MPTA"}}}
10-05 23:01:53.465 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44996
10-05 23:01:53.465 D: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
10-05 23:01:53.467 D: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={d={v=5, h=s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com, ts=1475697713467, s=aiVwAqOfKkxgXWZdYejceVrlivZ8MPTA}, t=h}, t=c}
10-05 23:01:53.468 D: conn_1 - Got control message: {d={v=5, h=s-usc1c-nss-105.firebaseio.com, ts=1475697713467, s=aiVwAqOfKkxgXWZdYejceVrlivZ8MPTA}, t=h}
10-05 23:01:53.468 D: conn_1 - realtime connection established
10-05 23:01:53.468 D: pc_0 - onReady
10-05 23:01:53.468 D: pc_0 - handling timestamp
10-05 23:01:53.475 D: pc_0 - Sending first connection stats
10-05 23:01:53.476 D: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={a=s, r=0, b={c={sdk.android.3-0-0=1}}}, t=d}
10-05 23:01:53.476 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44989
10-05 23:01:53.481 D: pc_0 - calling restore state
10-05 23:01:53.482 D: pc_0 - Not restoring auth because token is null.
10-05 23:01:53.482 D: pc_0 - Restoring outstanding listens
10-05 23:01:53.482 D: pc_0 - Restoring listen / (params: {})
10-05 23:01:53.484 D: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={a=q, r=1, b={h=, p=/}}, t=d}
10-05 23:01:53.486 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44991
10-05 23:01:53.491 D: pc_0 - Restoring writes.
10-05 23:01:53.648 D: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":0,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
10-05 23:01:53.649 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44838
10-05 23:01:53.649 D: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
10-05 23:01:53.649 D: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={r=0, b={d=, s=ok}}, t=d}
10-05 23:01:53.649 D: conn_1 - received data message: {r=0, b={d=, s=ok}}
10-05 23:01:54.114 D: ws_1 - ws message: 368
10-05 23:01:54.114 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44534
10-05 23:01:54.114 D: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 368
10-05 23:01:54.415 D: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"","d":{"route":{"autobuss-nr-1-autoosta-regionala-slimnica-celinieku-ciemats":{"routes":{"0":{"lat":"55.871109","lng":"26.523550"},"1":{"lat":"55.869579","lng":"26.519173"},"2":{"lat":"55.868752","lng":"26.519945"},"3":{"lat":"55.866943","lng":"26.514666"},"4":{"lat":"55.865353","lng":"26.520460"},"5":{"lat":"55.866463","lng":"26.525246"},"6":{"lat":"55.867714","lng":"26.530544"},"7":{"lat":"55.868931","lng":"26.535587"},"8":{"lat":"55.869690","lng":"26.538033"},"9":{"lat":"55.870590","lng":"26.539707"},"10":{"lat":"55.872761","lng":"26.543268"},"11":{"lat":"55.875336","lng":"26.547388"},"12":{"lat":"55.877731","lng":"26.551596"},"13":{"lat":"55.880199","lng":"26.555521"},"14":{"lat":"55.880825","lng":"26.556894"},"15":{"lat":"55.881340","lng":"26.558439"},"16":{"lat":"55.882389","lng":"26.561680"},"17":{"lat":"55.884327","lng":"26.567753"},"18":{"lat":"55.888271","lng":"26.580027"},"19":{"lat":"55.890450","lng":"26.580734"},"20":{"lat":"55.893158","lng":"26.581539"},"21":{"lat":"55.898533","lng":"26.583214"},"22":{"lat":"55.898766","lng":"26.588503"},"23":{"lat":"55.895168","lng":"26.590389"},"24":{"lat":"55.891716","lng":"26.592793"},"25":{"lat":"55.893604","lng":"26.600262"},"26":{"lat":"55.894588","lng":"26.604059"},"27":{"lat":"55.895119","lng":"26.606291"},"28":{"lat":"55.895420","lng":"26.607019"},"29":{"lat":"55.895721","lng":"26.607342"},"30":{"lat":"55.898380","lng":"26.609659"},"31":{"lat":"55.901489","lng":"26.612568"},"32":{"lat":"55.904564","lng":"26.615345"},"33":{"lat":"55.907810","lng":"26.618135"}},"stations":{"0":{"decription":"","geo":{"lat":"55.870842","lng":"26.525305"},"htlist":{"0":"06:25","1":"07:25","2":"08:30","3":"11:05","4":"12:20","5":"13:45","6":"15:10","7":"16:25","8":"17:40"},"name":"Autoosta","number":"1","other":{"0":{"link":"autobuss-nr-1-autoosta-regionala-slimnica-celinieku-ciemats","name":"Autoosta – reģionālā slimnīca – Ceļinieku ciemats","number":"1","ohtlist":{"0":"06:25","1":"07:25","2":"08:30","3":"11:05","4":"12:20","5":"13:45","6":"15:10","7":"16:25","8":"17:40"},"owtlist":{"0":"06:25","1":"07:25","2":"08:30","3":"11:05","4":"12:20","5":"13:45","6":"15:10","7":"16:25","8":"17:40"},"sid":"8768"},"1":{"link":"autobuss-nr-1a-autoosta-celinieku-ciemats","name":"Autoosta - Ceļinieku ciemats","number":"1A","owtlist":{"0":"06:50"},"sid":"8768"},"2":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3-autoosta-kooperativs","name":"Autoosta – Jaunie Stropi (Kooperatīvs)","number":"3","ohtlist":{"0":"07:50","1":"09:00","2":"10:30","3":"11:40","4":"12:50","5":"14:00","6":"15:00","7":"16:10","8":"17:20","9":"18:35","10":"19:50"},"owtlist":{"0":"05:48","1":"06:35","2":"07:50","3":"09:00","4":"10:30","5":"11:40","6":"12:50","7":"14:00","8":"15:00","9":"16:10","10":"17:20","11":"18:35","12":"19:50"},"sid":"8768"},"3":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3b-autoosta-ziglier-masinbuve","name":"Autoosta – Spaļu iela – Zieglera Mašīnbūve","number":"3B","ohtlist":{"0":"07:05","1":"08:05","2":"09:05","3":"10:35","4":"11:25","5":"12:20","6":"13:15","7":"14:45","8":"15:35","9":"16:30","10":"17:25","11":"18:20","12":"19:50","13":"20:40","14":"21:30"},"owtlist":{"0":"05:35","1":"06:17","2":"07:05","3":"08:05","4":"09:05","5":"10:35","6":"11:25","7":"12:20","8":"13:15","9":"14:45","10":"15:35","11":"16:30","12":"17:25","13":"18:20","14":"19:50","15":"20:40","16":"21:30"},"sid":"8768"},"4":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3c-autoosta-ziglier-masinbuve","name":"Autoosta – Maiznieks – Spaļu iela","number":"3C","ohtlist":{"0":"08:00","1":"08:50","2":"09:40","3":"11:15","4":"12:05","5":"13:00","6":"13:55","7":"15:25","8":"16:20","9":"17:15","10":"18:10","11":"19:08"},"owtlist":{"0":"06:05","1":"06:58","2":"08:00","3":"08:50","4":"09:40","5":"11:15","6":"12:05","7":"13:00","8":"13:55","9":"15:25","10":"16:20","11":"17:15","12":"18:10","13":"19:08"},"sid":"8768"},"5":{"link":"autobuss-nr-4-autoosta-cietoksnis-mezciems-autoosta","name":"Autoosta – Cietoksnis – Mežciems – Autoosta","number":"4","ohtlist":{"0":"05:15","1":"06:20","2":"07:20","3":"08:20","4":"09:
10-05 23:01:54.417 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44697
10-05 23:01:54.594 D: ws_1 - ws message: s-nr-21-daugavpils-ao-cietoksnis","name":"Daugavpils AO - Cietoksnis-Mežciems-Viduspoguļanka-Jaunforštadte-Daugavpils AO","number":"21","ohtlist":{"0":"03:40","1":"04:40"},"owtlist":{"0":"03:40","1":"04:40"},"sid":"8768"},"27":{"link":"autobuss-nr-22-autobusu-parks-krizi","name":"Autobusu parks –  Daugavpils AO – Nīderkuni – Judovka – Ruģeļi-Jaunbūve –  Ķimiķu c-ts-Jaunstropi – Vecstropi –  Križi","number":"22","ohtlist":{"0":"01:10"},"owtlist":{"0":"01:10"},"sid":"8768"},"28":{"link":"autobuss-nr-22-krizi-autobusu-parks","name":"Križi – Vecstropi – Jaunstropi-Ķimiķu c-ts – Jaunbūve-Ruģeļi – Nīderkuni – Daugavpils AO – Autobusu parks","number":"22","ohtlist":{"0":"04:00","1":"05:15"},"owtlist":{"0":"04:00","1":"05:15"},"sid":"8768"},"29":{"link":"autobuss-nr-23-rugeli-regionala-slimnica","name":"Ruģeļi - Reģionālā slimnīca","number":"23","owtlist":{"0":"06:57","1":"-","2":"15:35"},"sid":"8768"},"30":{"link":"autobuss-nr-14-autoosta-cietoksnis-kimija-autoosta","name":"Autoosta - Cietoksnis – Ķīmiķu ciemats (ar iebraukšanu Plaušu centrā)","number":"14","owtlist":{"0":"06:25","1":"07:04","2":"07:58","3":"15:30","4":"16:45"},"sid":"8768"}},"sid":"8768","wtlist":{"0":"06:25","1":"07:25","2":"08:30","3":"11:05","4":"12:20","5":"13:45","6":"15:10","7":"16:25","8":"17:40"}},"1":{"decription":"","geo":{"lat":"55.867573","lng":"26.516882"},"htlist":{"0":"06:27","1":"07:27","2":"08:32","3":"11:07","4":"12:22","5":"13:47","6":"15:12","7":"16:27","8":"17:42"},"name":"Daugavas iela","number":"1","other":{"0":{"link":"autobuss-nr-1-autoosta-regionala-slimnica-celinieku-ciemats","name":"Autoosta – reģionālā slimnīca – Ceļinieku ciemats","number":"1","ohtlist":{"0":"06:27","1":"07:27","2":"08:32","3":"11:07","4":"12:22","5":"13:47","6":"15:12","7":"16:27","8":"17:42"},"owtlist":{"0":"06:27","1":"07:27","2":"08:32","3":"11:07","4":"12:22","5":"13:47","6":"15:12","7":"16:27","8":"17:42"},"sid":"8769"},"1":{"link":"autobuss-nr-1a-autoosta-celinieku-ciemats","name":"Autoosta - Ceļinieku ciemats","number":"1A","owtlist":{"0":"06:52"},"sid":"8769"},"2":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3-autoosta-kooperativs","name":"Autoosta – Jaunie Stropi (Kooperatīvs)","number":"3","ohtlist":{"0":"07:52","1":"09:02","2":"10:32","3":"11:42","4":"12:52","5":"14:02","6":"15:02","7":"16:12","8":"17:22","9":"18:37","10":"19:52"},"owtlist":{"0":"05:50","1":"06:37","2":"07:52","3":"09:02","4":"10:32","5":"11:42","6":"12:52","7":"14:02","8":"15:02","9":"16:12","10":"17:22","11":"18:37","12":"19:52"},"sid":"8769"},"3":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3b-autoosta-ziglier-masinbuve","name":"Autoosta – Spaļu iela – Zieglera Mašīnbūve","number":"3B","ohtlist":{"0":"07:07","1":"08:07","2":"09:07","3":"10:37","4":"11:27","5":"12:22","6":"13:17","7":"14:47","8":"15:37","9":"16:32","10":"17:27","11":"18:22","12":"19:52","13":"20:42","14":"21:32"},"owtlist":{"0":"05:37","1":"06:19","2":"07:07","3":"08:07","4":"09:07","5":"10:37","6":"11:27","7":"12:22","8":"13:17","9":"14:47","10":"15:37","11":"16:32","12":"17:27","13":"18:22","14":"19:52","15":"20:42","16":"21:32"},"sid":"8769"},"4":{"link":"autobuss-nr-3c-autoosta-ziglier-masinbuve","name":"Autoosta – Maiznieks – Spaļu iela","number":"3C","ohtlist":{"0":"08:02","1":"08:52","2":"09:42","3":"11:17","4":"12:07","5":"13:02","6":"13:57","7":"15:27","8":"16:22","9":"17:17","10":"18:12","11":"19:10"},"owtlist":{"0":"06:07","1":"07:00","2":"08:02","3":"08:52","4":"09:42","5":"11:17","6":"12:07","7":"13:02","8":"13:57","9":"15:27","10":"16:22","11":"17:17","12":"18:12","13":"19:10"},"sid":"8769"},"5":{"link":"autobuss-nr-6-autoosta-niderkuni","name":"Autoosta - Nīderkūni","number":"6","ohtlist":{"0":"07:52","1":"08:32","2":"09:12","3":"10:52","4":"11:42","5":"12:22","6":"13:02","7":"13:42","8":"14:27","9":"15:42","10":"16:22","11":"17:02","12":"17:42","13":"18:22","14":"19:02","15":"19:42","16":"20:42"},"owtlist":{"0":"06:32","1":"07:12","2":"07:52","3":"08:32","4":"09:12","5":"10:52","6":"11:42","7":"12:22","8":"13:02","
10-05 23:01:54.594 D: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44822
```

After that a lot of output with:
[image]

And this all finish with:

[image]

[image]

I'm using default bandwidth.

Comment: Getting data from Firebase in a single listener like this is mostly a factor of the data size vs the bandwidth. What bandwidth is the connection you are on?

Comment: You might also get some insight into where the time goes by enabling debug logging and inspecting the wire info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)

Comment: Does that happen when you first start listening to that reference or everytime the value is changed ? Usually I experience this response time only when I first start listening but then too it never crossed 45seconds mark **( considering network and processing time)** . After that it's almost directly proportional to bandwidth. 5mb json snapshot takes 2-4seconds(avg) on 30mbps. In short, never experienced such high response time. Probably it got something to do with the device this app runs and network connectivity. Try to catch real culprit and then do update it here. I would like to know.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using the default bandwidth, you can see my logs

Comment: @NishantDubey updated

Comment: The first log looks reasonable and no noticeable gaps in there, I skipped the others. The transfer time is almost always: data size / connection speed, with (as Nishant says) some overhead for the initial establishing of the connection. What type of connection are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found ?

The Firebase is bad working with the large structured data (I don't believe that I can make problems for GOOGLE with the size of json 5mb, but it happens).

My approach is: to reduce loading time I need to avoid requesting all data in one time.

Better to divide it to several requests.

To simplify my JSON:

```
{
  routes: {
    routeName: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName1: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName2: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName3: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName4: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName5: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    }
  },
  routesReverse: {
    routeName: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName1: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName2: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName3: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName4: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    },
    routeName5: {
      gpsData: {

      },
      timeData: {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problems were with this code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "I'm started");
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I'm finished");
            }
        }
```

The problem was gone:

```
Log.d(TAG, "I'm started");
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("route").child("routeName2");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "I'm finished");
            }
        }
```

And the time reduced from 2-3 minutes to 2-3 seconds.